# Какой парсер может парсить только <head> игнорируя body(не скачивая body)

Tags: html, парсер, scrapy

Уже долго выискиваю быстрые html парсеры для парсинга большого количества сайтов(очень) и пока что знаю только 2 хороших варианта - zombie.js и scrapy. Оба достаточно быстрые но у них обоих есть минус - если парсится страница то скачивается тоже вся страница, нельзя к примеру собрать только значения тайтлов или скриптов(`<script>`) в `<head>` без скачивания `<body>` а это очень напрягает сервер при больших страницах.

Кто знает, напишите быстрые аналоги этих парсеров с схожей функцией(если такие есть). Буду очень благодарен

Comment: lxml + async + aiohttp

Comment: lxml умеет игнорировать body? Изучал его и вроде не видел такой функции. Не подскажете точней?

Comment: Основная проблема не столько в скорости сколько в том, что бы меньше нагружать сервер при огромных обьемах парсинга(300+ сайтов в минуту на пример). Сейчас сижу и могу парсить вплоть по 18-240 страниц в секунду. при concurrency request 64 и download dellay 0.33

Comment: на scrapy-парсере

Comment: 180-240 товаров в минуту**

Comment: нужно искать парсеры, которые дают возможность парсить по ходу скачивания. Тогда можно прервать получение страницы, если все необходимое получено.

Comment: сидел но не нарыл особо информации куда копать... Единственное что заметил так это селениумовский метод прерывания загрузки страницы если контент спаршен и у scrapy в download middleware get на head поменять

Comment: Не тестировал но если эти методы не сработают то уж не знаю, довольствоватся 3 страницами в секунду? или как то страницу в кеш запихнуть и дать понять scrapy что не надо прогружать.